# What is the right way (Best practice) for dequeue a reusable cell in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm want to dequeue a cell for use in the table view but I'm afraid that I'm doing it in the wrong way.

Currently I'm doing this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    //Configure the atributes here.            

    return cell
}
```

What I'm  really want to know is if it is right or I have to check if the cell is nil?

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as CustomCell

if cell == nil {
    cell = CustomCell()
}
```

What code are correct? If none of them are right witch way is the right way?

Answer (score 2):

Just forced unwrap the cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
...
return cell
```

Since **you** have designed the cell in Interface Builder a crash will reveal a design error.

Comment: But fore a unwrap sounds a little hack don't you think?

Comment: No, it is not. If all connections and identifiers are set correctly the line can / will never cause a crash at runtime.

Comment: i try using same and it's always return nil every time could you help?

Comment: @ȜAmerElsayed The code returns a cell or it crashes, it will never return `nil`